# VS code set up for c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-code

I am new in VS code. I wrote a C++ code like one below. but unfortunately in the terminal or output panel I cannot get both of the string and variable value. in the terminal only variable's inputted value is showing. How to fix this?

```
 #include <bits/stdc++.h>  

 int main() 
 {     
     int slices; 
     std::cin >> slices;
     std::cout << "You got " << slices << " of pizzas" << std::endl;
     return 0;
 }
```

[image]

Comment: In the terminal you're not interacting with your program all all, you're interacting with PowerShell.

Comment: Here's a step-by-step guide to setup cpp on vscode... https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw

Comment: You don't appear to actually run your program. You just type the numbers into the command interpreter.

Comment: @jkb I don't see any other option leaving powershell in there... can you suggest how can I solve?

Comment: @anondolok I wasn't suggesting that you remove PowerShell, I was just pointing out that you weren't actually working with your program when typing in the terminal. I suggest you follow the guide that Aditya Patnaik pointed you to.